# Как получить информацию о подключенных к компьютеру устройствах C#

Tags: c#, windows-10

В Windows 10 появилась возможность раздавать WiFi (Мобильный хот-спот), можно ли как-то получить информацию о подключенных устройствах, программно отключать устройства ит.д ?.

Comment: Каждой точке выдаётся ip. Снифером можно поймать пакет от "нового" ip - таким образом обнаружить новое устройство. А вот как отключить... Если можно в меню винды то скорее всего смотреть WMI

Answer (score 4):

Для этого есть специальный класс [`WiFiAdapter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.wifi.wifiadapter). Вот [официальный пример](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/WiFiScan/cs/Scenario1_CachedNetworks.xaml.cs) опроса списка устройств:

```
var result = await WiFiAdapter.RequestAccessAsync();
if (result != WiFiAccessStatus.Allowed)
{
    // ошибка, нету доступа
}
else
{
    IReadOnlyList<WiFiAdapter> wiFiAdapters = await WiFiAdapter.FindAllAdaptersAsync();
    foreach (WiFiAdapter adapter in wiFiAdapters)
    {
        // тут у вас будет текущий адаптер, делайте с ним что хотите
    }
}
```

Не забудьте [заказать разрешение `wiFiControl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations) в манифесте.